# How do you resolve a circular dependency with an inner class?

Tags: java, circular-dependency, anonymous-inner-class

(Java question)

If I reference a field in an inner class, does this cause a circular dependency between the enclosing class and the inner class?

How can I avoid this?

Here is an example:

```
public class Outer {

  private Other o;
  private Inner i;    

  public Outer() {
    o = new Other();

    i = new Inner() {
      public void doSomething() {
        o.foo();
      }
    };

  }
}
```

Comment: Outer, Other, Inner do you mean to have three classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Static vs instance class:** If you declare the inner class as static then the instances of the inner class doesn't have any reference to the outer class. If it's not satic then your inner object efectivelly points to the outer object that created it (it has an implicit reference, in fact, if you use reflection over its constructors you'll see an extra parameter for receiving the outer instance).

**Inner instance points outer instance:** Circular reference is in case each instance points the other one. A lot of times you use inner classes for elegantly implementing some interface and accessing private fields while not implementing the interface with the outer class. It does mean inner instance points outer instance but doesn't mean the opposite. Not necesary a circular reference.

**Closing the circle:** Anyway there's nothing wrong with circular referencing in Java. Objects work nicely and when they're not more referenced they're garbage collected. It doesn't matter if they point each other.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using in the example is a little off there is no declaration of the class or interface Inner. But there isn't anything wrong with the concept of the example. In Java it will work fine.

I'm not sure what you're doing here, but you may want to consider a more simple design for maintainability etc.

It's a common pattern for anonymous event handlers to reference elements of their parent class, so no reason to avoid it if that's the case, that's how Java was designed instead of having function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure if this is what you are asking...)

At runtime, the inner class has an implicit reference to the instance of the outer class it belongs to.  So whenever you pass the inner class instance around, you are also passing the outer class instance around.
You can avoid that by declaring the inner class as "static", but that means that the inner class can't access member variables of the outer class.  So in that case if you want to  access a member of the outer class, you need to pass it explicitly to the inner class (using a setter or using the constructor of the inner class).